# extract from python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, extract

Lets say my dictionary is the following:

```
class Airplane:

    def __init__(self, colour, Airplane_type): 
        self.colour = colour
        self.Airplane_type = Airplane_type

    def is_Airplane(self):
        return self.Airplane_type=="Jet"

    def is_orange(self):
          return self.colour=="orange"


class Position:

    def __init__(self, horizontal, vertical):
        self.horizontal = int(horizontal)
        self.vertical = int(vertical)





from airplane import Airplane
from position import Position

Class test():

    def __init__(self):

    self.landings:{Position(1,0) : Airplane("Jet", "orange"),
                   Position(3,0) : Airplane("Boeing", "blue"),}
```

How do I extract all the orange airplanes and return the number of orange planes for instance.

Comment: waht is `Position` a function or just a string??

Comment: im sorry ill add it to the code

Comment: it should be `self.landings = {.....`

Comment: also show us what `Position` and `Airplane` will return

Comment: It would help if you provided the constructor for Airplane, you'd need some way of getting the colour given an Airplane instance. (I would assume that `plane1.color` would return `"orange"` and `"blue"` respectively, for instance.)

Comment: How can I retrieve the position of the orange airplanes in the dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elegant way of doing this would be with a list comprehension:

```
oranges = [plane for plane in self.landings.itervalues()
           if plane.is_orange()]
```

As M. K. Hunter said, you can call len() on the list to get the number.

Comment: Rather than indexing `self.landings` twice, you'd probably be better off iterating over `self.landings.values()` (or `.itervalues()` if you're using Python 2).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Edited to reflect that (I do assume Python 2 unless 3 is mentioned, to be honest.)

Answer (score 1):

This code should give you the result you want:

```
result = []
keys = []
for key in self.landings:
    if self.landings[key].color == "orange":
        result.append(self.landings[key])
        keys.append(key)
#at the end of the loop, "result" has all the orange planes
#at the end of the loop, "keys" has all the keys of the orange planes
number=len(result) #len(result) gives the number of orange planes
```

Note that `len` will work in many situations for the number of x in a list or dictionary.

Comment: Might want to do `.color == "orange"` rather than `=`.

Comment: How can I retrieve the position of the orange airplanes in the dictionary?

Comment: I added two new lines to render the set of keys which correspond to the orange airplanes.

Comment: You are welcome. It looks like you are trying to accept both my answer and Arda Xi's answer. His is actually better -- more pythonic. I voted for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the position of the orange airplanes, you probably want to iterate over the `items` of the dictionary so that you can both test the color of the plane and at the same time see the position:

```
orange_plane_positions = [pos for pos, plane in self.landings.values()
                              if plane.is_orange()]
```

If you're using Python 2 and you have many values in the `self.landings` dictionary, it might be better to use `iteritems` rather than `items` directly (the latter is always best in Python 3).

Note that if this query is something you expect to do frequently, it might make sense to use a different dictionary organization. Rather than indexing by position, index by plane color and store the position as an attribute of the `Airplane` instance.